# How to prove that atoms must be countable for finite measures?

Tags: measure-theory

Quoting [@Lazy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/958820/lazy) answering [Set of atoms must be countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262888/set-of-atoms-must-be-countable)

> If there are uncountably many atoms there has to be a set in any countable partition that contains uncountably many of these. But any uncountable set of singletons with positive mass has countable subsets with arbitrarily large measure. So the set cannot have finite measure.

In the definition of a measure it says
$$
A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \implies \mu(A) ≤ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_k)
$$
and for subadditivity
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) ≤ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_k)
$$

So even if any of these $A_k$s has infinite measure and hence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_k)=\infty$ that just means that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) ≤ \infty$ which could be *anything*.

I don't understand which concept I'm missing here. Could someone please explain in more detail?

Comment: The singletons are disjoint, thus, you can use countable additivity and you get that the union has infinite measure.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much! I totally forgot about that one.

Comment: I suggest you write up some answer. Then you can make sure that you properly understand what is going on, get some feedback and can also earn some reputation :)